# Interpretting Logarithmic Residuals as Percent Change from Average

Tags: residuals, logarithm

Suppose I'm running a regression that looks something like

$log(price)=β_0+β_1log(X)+β_2log(X)^2$.

I have found the residuals, grouped them according to the number of sellers in the observation's town, and calculated the mean residual for each group. Suppose the residuals are 0.05 for 1 seller, -0.01 for 2 sellers, -0.02 for 3 sellers.

I want to make a statement about the %markup to the average price for each group.

Since these are logged residuals, can I just interpret the mean residual as the %markup from the average price? (eg. there is a 5% markup from the average price when there is 1 seller, -1% when there are 2, etc.)

Or will I need to calculate the %change by comparing the average+markup to the average? Which would take the form of: $100×\frac{residual}{meanLogPrice}?$

Comment: Welcome to CV, Amy.  It's always worth searching our site before posting a question: in this case, your classmate beat you to it by nine hours.